# Add usernames to Twitter List

Tags: jquery, api, twitter, tweepy

I read this article about creating a list from tweepy API:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-api-create_list-in-tweepy/

I wonder if once the list object is created, can we add usernames to that list?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using the [`add_list_member`](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v4.10.0/api.html#tweepy.API.add_list_member) method:

> Add a member to a list. The authenticated user must own the list to be able to add members to it. Lists are limited to 5,000 members.

Note that this method (and the post you were reading) uses Twitter API v1.1 which is the legacy version. You probably want to look at [`tweepy.Client.add_list_member`](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v4.10.0/client.html#tweepy.Client.add_list_member) which uses v2 of the API.